# How do I see the versions that apt upgrade wants to use

Tags: apt, versions

When running `apt upgrade` I see a list of packages that will be upgraded. However, I would like to see the versions that would be upgraded, similar as it happens when using `conda upgrade` or `pip x --upgrade`.

Is there any way to directly see which versions would be used? Without having to track down the specific packages manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command

```
apt list --upgradable
```

or, if you want to save some keystrokes, it's short version

```
apt list -u
```

is what you want to use to show the desired information.

Comment: Or if you're lazy like me `apt list -u`

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `aptitude` instead. With aptitude you can use `U` to mark all available upgrades, and then when you press `g` you get (as you do for *any* operation) a list of the packages that will be affected along with their current and to-be-installed versions. You can also view changelogs (with `C`) and you get some pretty advanced conflict resolution features, in case they're ever needed.